# yandex map regions достать районы

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В яндекс картах есть regions - модуль для отображения границ [регионов определенной страны](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/1.x/mod/concepts/regions-docpage/).

С российскими областями, округами, краями и тд он справляется прекрасно, но встала задача отрисовывать на карте границы районов внутри областей. Не нашёл в сети ответов поэтому задаю здесь.

Возможно ли с помощью этого модуля отрисовать на карте границы районов внутри областей? Если да - то как? Если нет - то как лучше? Рисовать полигоны вручную? И где лучше взять правильные координаты для определения границ районов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ссылка на версию 1.х - это устаревшая версия, которая уже не поддерживается. Её использовать не стоит.

В актуальной версии 2.1 есть [модуль Регионы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/?from=SO), но для него минимальной единицей АТД тоже является область. Более мелкие единицы деления достать не получится, потому что их просто нет в модуле.

**Что можно сделать:**

- Скачать границы нужных территорий из открытых источников, например, в geoJSON.
- Отобразить их на карте стандартными средствами JS API Яндекса (через [`geoQuery`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geoQuery.xml?from=SO) как в [примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones?from=SO))